# behavior of builtin functions when assigned as class attributes

Tags: python

I would like to assign a function as class attribute, and have it so when accessed through instance, it is still unbounded. I understand that this can be achieved with using `staticmethod` descriptor. But it seems the behavior is different for the builtin functions, and I would like to replicate that.

```py
def abs_(value):
    return abs(value)


class Test:

    func_1 = abs
    func_2 = len
    func_3 = abs_
    func_4 = staticmethod(abs_)


>>> test = Test()
>>> test.func_1
<built-in function abs>
>>> test.func_2
<built-in function len>
>>> test.func_3
<bound method abs_ of <__main__.Test object at 0x10436d910>>
```

In this case, the builtin function are unbound, and the defined function `abs_` is bound to the instance. And obviously all functions work except `func_3` since it is bound method.

```py
>>> test.func_1(-1)
1
>>> test.func_3(-1)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: abs_() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

How does builtin function achieve this, and is there a way to replicate the behavior (remain unbound)? Thank you!

Comment: It seems like `func_4` does which for some reason you didn't include in the outputs...

Comment: Have a look at https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html#static-methods-and-class-methods. Builtin functions (abs, at least, I didn't check any other) don't have a `__get__()` method, unlike user defined functions.